# what is the best way to change Heap size of Jmeter which gives :OutOfMemoryError

Tags: jmeter, heap-size

I am trying to change the size of my jmeter(version 4) heap size from  set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m to more as i have system with 64bit, 16GB RAM but unable to change it.

i have tried a lot but nothing works for me.

can any one here help me out with this issues.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter version 4 comes with 1 GB of HEAP allocated **by default**, you can amend it like:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1G -Xmx10G && jmeter.bat
```

You can also locate the following line in *jmeter.bat* file:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

and amend this `-Xmx1g` according to your requirements. Don't allocate too much heap as it might get things worse, don't set too low as your test will be slowed down by the [garbage collection](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html). You can check heap state and other VM metrics using i.e. [JVisualVM tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html)

More information:

- [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T for your time to answer sir but when i run jmeter.bat from my cmd it shows  HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m this which creates OutOfMemoryError during load test can i change this 256m to some more GB so that there shouldn't have generated OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the bin folder of JMeter
   apache-jmeter- -> bin
2. Right-click and open jmeter.bat file in notepad or notepad++ (with Admin rights)
3. Search for the keyword ‘set Heap’
   You can see the default heap size (1 GB – may vary in your JMeter version)

```
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

3. Change the -Xms (initial heap size) and -Xmx (maximum heap size) values.

   ```
   set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
   ```
4. Save your Changes and restart JMeter

**How to validate the applied changes?**

1. Launch a new instance of JMeter
2. Add a ‘Thread Group‘
3. Add a ‘JSR223 Sample’ under the ‘Thread Group’
4. Paste the below code in the ‘Script’ section

   ```
   java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().each {
         log.info("Effective JVM argument: " + "$it")
   }
   ```
5. Run the test
6. Check the JVM argument values in the log by clicking the yellow colour triangle in the right corner.