# how to extend HEAP SIZE of jMeter 5.1.1 on Windows 10

Tags: java, jmeter, heap-size

I have problem with Heap Size in jMeter and I need to increase the heap size.
I try change in jmeter.bat but in console (when I open gui mode) the displayed info is still default option.

How can I extend the heap size in my jMeter? I need step by step information.

My environment is:

- jMeter 5.1.1
- Java 8
- Windows 10.

When I check in gui mode in JSR223 Listener with groovy script

```
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().each {
    log.info("Effective JVM argument: " + "$it")
}
```

In console I see good value what I create in jmeter.bat.

Can  I believe in the groovy script info or what is displayed in the console when I open gui mode?

btw. for test I am using non gui mode, but I was be curious which info is true.

Comment: See as well the information in this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512390/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-heap-size-of-jmeter-which-gives-outofmemoryerror as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586174/jmeter-how-to-increase-heap-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter, how to increase heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586174/jmeter-how-to-increase-heap-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change your script to use [println() function](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#println())

   ```
   java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().each {
       println("Effective JVM argument: " + "$it")
   }
   ```
2. [Run your JMeter script in command-line non-GUI mode like](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/)

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx
   ```
3. You should see default [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) heap settings: `-Xms1g` and `-Xmx1g`
4. Now set HEAP [environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) to increase the lower limit to 5G and the upper limit to 10G

   set "HEAP=-Xms5g -Xmx10g"
5. Re-run your JMeter script - you should see the updated values:

   [image]
6. If you want the change to be permanent you need to amend [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/jmeter.bat#L150) of the `jmeter.bat` file:

   ```
   set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
   ```

   to contain whatever values you want

Answer (score 0):

open cmd  command line  on  Windows:

```
1.jps -l              #view  jmeter  process
2.jinfo -flags  pid    #jmeter pid
```